# Mac equivalent of /etc/nsswitch.conf for PHP chroot

Tags: mac, dns, php

I've setup a chroot for my PHP server running behind nginx on mac.

It works except for any call to a CURL request fails with an error like `cURL resource: Resource id #43; cURL error: Couldn't resolve host 's3.amazonaws.com'`

Most guides to setting up a chroot environment say that you should map certain files to be available inside the chroot. The only file I can't find to map is `/etc/nsswitch.conf` which apparently doesn't exist on Mac.

What is the equivalent file on a Mac? Or what file/socket should be made available to the chroot environment to allow DNS lookups to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that on OSX the DNS lookup is done through the service mDNSResponder service which is running as a socket at /var/run/mDNSResponder.

It does not use /etc/nsswitch.conf or /etc/resolv.conf so there is no way of mapping those files into a chroot. Instead it's a better idea to use a localhost proxy.